# How can I edit my applied job on Developer Jobs?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied job request on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs and I have mention all the details as below:

[image]

Unfortunatelly I selected auto chrome filling form and my name is changed which I saw after applied.

So any way to change that name or I have to apply again?

Any help please?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no editing option once the application is submitted. What I would suggest is if the Employer contacts you back for further discussion, you can specify the mistake you committed with your details.

I feel edit wasn't added, since these mistakes aren't common, but on the other hand this can be a `feature-request`.

Good luck.